# How can I retrieve an updated script in the oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I retrieve an updated script in the oracle database?
An incorrect script was run in the oracle database. I want to get this script back. how can I do that? The script is as follows.

```
--52 record
 update cons.paymentplan_detail         det set det.payment_date = to_char(ADD_MONTHS(to_Date (det.payment_date, 'YYYYMMDD'),3),'YYYYMMDD')
where det.oid in (select det.oid
  from cons.instalment_instalment_loan ins,
       cons.paymentplan_detail         det,
       cons.paymentplan_def            def,
       (select ins.loans_reference_no,min(det.payment_date) as payment_date
            from cons.instalment_instalment_loan ins,
                cons.paymentplan_detail         det,
                cons.paymentplan_def            def
            where ins.loan_state in ('OPEN', 'BLOCKED')
               and ins.status = '1'
               and def.status = '1'
               and det.status = '1'
               and ins.payment_plan_oid = det.payment_plan_oid
               and det.plan_detail_status  in ('NO','LT')
               and ins.OID='251pfek38q43fg00'
               and def.oid = det.payment_plan_oid
               and def.payment_plan_status = 'GR'
               and def.credit_oid = ins.oid
             group by ins.loans_reference_no) t
 where ins.loan_state in ('OPEN', 'BLOCKED')
   and ins.status = '1'
   and def.status = '1'
   and det.status = '1'
   and ins.payment_plan_oid = det.payment_plan_oid
   and det.plan_detail_status  in ('NO')
   and ins.OID='251pfek38q43fg00'
   and def.oid = det.payment_plan_oid
   and def.payment_plan_status = 'GR'
   and def.credit_oid = ins.oid
   and t.loans_reference_no = ins.loans_reference_no
 group by det.oid);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get this script back"? Do you want to reverse the effects of the script or do you want to get the text of a previously run script?

Comment: I don't understand. An incorrect script was run. And you want to know what it looked like exactly? And you show us what it looked like? Is what you are showing only close to that script and you want to see the real script for comparision? SQL statements can be seen for some time in the V$SQL view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't `COMMIT`ted the data then use `ROLLBACK`.

Otherwise, your solution could be as simple as running the same query but subtracting 3 months:

```sql
update cons.paymentplan_detail det
set det.payment_date = to_char(
                         ADD_MONTHS(
                           to_Date (det.payment_date, 'YYYYMMDD'),
                           -3             -- Changed from +3 to -3
                         ),
                         'YYYYMMDD'
                       )
where ...
```

If that won't work and you have `COMMIT`ted the data and the database has flashback activated then you can use a flashback query to find the old data from before the `UPDATE`.

If all that fails, then you can look and see if the database has a recent backup you can restore from.

Comment: it is worth to mention that you can use flashback query without having flashback activated at database level, as long as the data is still in the undo tablespace.